# How to fit image data correctly to a model in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

i am trying to trained a cnn model, but i really don't understand how to do it properly. i still learning about this kind of stuff so i'm really lost. I already tried doing stuff with it but still cannot get my head around it. can someone explain to me how to do it properly. when i try to fit the train data to the model this error pops up.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 224, 224, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Skripsi/Program/training.py", line 80, in <module>
    train.train()
  File "G:/Skripsi/Program/training.py", line 70, in train
    model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, epochs=2, verbose=1)
  File "G:\Skripsi\Program\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "G:\Skripsi\Program\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1129, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:
    File "G:\Skripsi\Program\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "G:\Skripsi\Program\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "G:\Skripsi\Program\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "G:\Skripsi\Program\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 808, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "G:\Skripsi\Program\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "G:\Skripsi\Program\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 227, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model" (type Functional).
        Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
        Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

this is my code for training the model.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from densenet201 import DenseNet201
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

dataset_folder = "./datasets/train_datasets"


class TrainingPreprocessing:

    @staticmethod
    def preprocessing_train(path):
        images = cv2.imread(path, 3)
        images_resize = cv2.resize(src=images, dsize=(224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        images_normalize = cv2.normalize(images_resize, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX,
                                         dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
        return images_normalize.reshape(224, 224, 3)


class Training:

    @staticmethod
    def load_data():
        """Loads and Preprocess dataset"""
        train_labels_encode = []
        train_labels = []
        train_data = []

        file_list = os.listdir(dataset_folder)
        for folder in file_list:
            file_list2 = os.listdir(str(dataset_folder) + '/' + str(folder))
            for images in file_list2:
                train_labels_encode.append(folder)
                train_labels.append(folder)
                train_data.append(np.array(TrainingPreprocessing.preprocessing_train(
                    str(dataset_folder) + '/' + str(folder) + '/' + str(images)
                )))

        labels = np.array(train_labels_decode)
        data = np.array(train_data)
        return labels, data

    def split_data(self):
        """Split the preprocessed dataset to train and test data"""
        x, y = self.load_data()
        self.x_train, self.x_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
        print('Training data shape : ', self.x_train.shape, self.y_train.shape)

        print('Testing data shape : ', self.x_test.shape, self.y_test.shape)

    def train(self):
        """Compile dan fit DenseNet model"""
        input_shape = 224, 224, 3
        number_classes = 2
        model = DenseNet201.densenet(input_shape, number_classes)
        model.summary()

        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
        model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, epochs=2, verbose=1)
        model.save_weights('densenet201_best_model.h5', overwrite=True)

        loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(self.x_test, self.y_test)

        print("[INFO] accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(accuracy * 100))


train = Training()
train.split_data()
train.train()
```

and this is the code for the cnn network

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ReLU, concatenate, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf


class DenseNet201:

    def densenet(image_shape, number_classes, growth_rate=32):

        def batch_relu_conv(x, growth_rate, kernel=1, strides=1):
            x = BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = ReLU()(x)
            x = Conv2D(growth_rate, kernel, strides=strides, padding='same', kernel_initializer="he_uniform")(x)
            return x

        def dense_block(x, repetition):
            for _ in range(repetition):
     

       y = batch_relu_conv(x, 4 * growth_rate)
            y = batch_relu_conv(y, growth_rate, 3)
            x = concatenate([y, x])
        return x

    def transition_layer(x):
        x = batch_relu_conv(x, K.int_shape(x)[-1] // 2)
        x = AveragePooling2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
        return x

    inputs = Input(image_shape)
    x = Conv2D(64, 7, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer="he_uniform")(inputs)
    x = MaxPool2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    for repetition in [6, 12, 48, 32]:
        d = dense_block(x, repetition)
        x = transition_layer(d)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D ()(d)

    output = Dense(number_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(inputs, output)
    return model
```

Comment: Please make your code smaller and create sample one to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you inverted data and labels (x and y) in the function:

`def load_data():` which returns: `return labels, data`

I think you are calling `model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, epochs=2, verbose=1)`
with label and then data. Hence the model complaining about not getting the expected data shape.